# processing 2 dimension array

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, multidimensional-array

I am working in classic ASP; using getRows to get multidimension array of rows and column.

while iterating a row; I want to pass that single row into another function to build the column layout.

with C# I can do this:

```
obj[][] multiDimArray = FunctionCall_To_InitializeArray_4X16();

for (int rowId = 0 ; rowId < 4 ; rowId++)
{
FunctionCall_to_ProcessSingleRow(multiDimArray[rowId][]); 
//this function only accept single dimension array
}
```

How can I do this is asp classic/vbscript:

```
1. I have a function that accept single dimension array as parameter.
2. Call that function and pass 1 part of 2 dimension array.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to populate a new array or dictionary object with the single dimension you want to process.

Answer (score 0):

here a piece from working code, should get you going..

```
aResults = oRst.Getrows
oRst.Close
Set oRst = Nothing
Call SubCloseDatabaseOracle
iRows = UBound(aResults, 2)
iCols = UBound(aResults, 1)
row = 1 'first row
line = ""
separator = ""
FOR col = 0 TO iCols
  line = line & separator & cStr(aResults(col,row))
  separator = ";"
NEXT 
aSingleDimensionArray = split(line,";")
```